# Apache2 installation fails on a Ubuntu computer with no access to internet

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, apache2, offline

I am trying to get *apache2* installed on a *Ubuntu 23.10.1* (desktop) computer that doesn't have any access to internet. But running into errors.

I have looked through a lot on the *askubuntu* forum and also on *Ubuntu* site but haven't found a working solution given my constraints (see setup details below). I have tried the steps mentioned on [AptGet/Offline/Repository](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Offline/Repository) but I still get the same errors for missing *apache2* libraries as I don't think I got the right files downloaded. Also, I have looked at other questions on offline installation - none of them seems specific to my setup and constraints; the solutions that seem close to my environment either refer to older unsupported software that doesn't work anymore (e.g. *Keryx*) or don't exactly work the same way specified.

Here is my setup:

- **Computer A**: Target system, *Ubuntu 23.10.1* (desktop), without any access to internet. This is where I want to setup the *apache2* (and later the full *LAMP* environment).
- **Computer B**: *Windows 11* computer which I used to download the *Ubuntu* desktop ISO. I also use it to manually download other software or '*dists*' which may be needed to complete the *LAMP* setup on Computer A. I copy files downloaded on Computer B using a USB drive to Computer A. My constraint is that I can not install any new software on this computer.
- Also, note that I do not have access to another *Ubuntu* system where I can use *Ubuntu* commands to download packages or update repositories and then take them over to Computer A.

So far this is the current status:

1. I have been able to successfully setup the *Ubuntu 23.10.1* desktop environment on Computer A in offline mode.
2. However, when I try to install *apache2* on Computer A, the installation fails with errors.

I am installing *apache2* using the following commands: `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt install apache2`.

After running `sudo apt update`, I get following messages after a bunch of other messages:

```
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/mantic/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I assumed that all packages are fine.

When I run `sudo apt install apache2`, I get the following errors:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apr/libapr1_1.7.2-3_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apr-util/libaprutil1_1.6.3-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apr-util/libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3_1.6.3-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apr-util/libaprutil1-ldap_1.6.3-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2-bin_2.4.57-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2-data_2.4.57-2ubuntu2_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2-utils_2.4.57-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2_2.4.57-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Trying with `--fix-missing` option also did not work and gave the same errors with an additional message "Unable to correct missing packages".

I think I am missing some setup and additional packages but don't know the right fix for this issue. Could anyone suggest a solution to get the *LAMP* environment setup on Computer A with no access to internet? Thanks!